# Solr Relevance Results

Tags: apache, solr, solrj, relevance

I am using Solr 5.0.0 for relevance search in my application.

I have fields like `productName`, `category`, `brand`, `price`, etc.

I am searching on `productName` field. I have two categories

- `laptops`
- `laptop bags`

Same like `mobile phones` and `mobile phone covers`. I have given an index time boosting for `mobiles` and `laptops` to get `laptops` when I search 'laptops'. But when I search for 'bags', it's showing `laptop with bag` first from `laptop`, because the name contained laptop with bag or without bag.

If I give index level boost to laptop bags category too, the i search for laptop , it will give laptop bags first. Same thing for other things also

How can i avoid this?